# Is startup on user login and setting persistence possible with Desktop Bridge or UWP on Surface Hub?

Tags: windows, startup, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge, surface-hub

I am exploring the potential of migrating an existing Windows service application to Desktop Bridge for compatibility with Surface Hub devices. I have two main inquiries:

1. Startup on User Login: Can a UWP or Desktop Bridge application run on user login on Surface Hub?
2. Persisting App Settings: Can app settings be maintained across different user sessions on Surface Hub?

I've tested the "TestStartup" app from [AppModelSamples](https://github.com/microsoft/AppModelSamples) (as mentioned [in this article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/)). Using remote debug with Surface Hub, I observed that while the app is added to Startup apps in Task Manager, its startup status reverts to "Disabled" after a user ends his session and then logs in again.

Comment: Did you manually launch the app? If you manually launch the app, the value is always disabled.

I made a sample followed the blog you shared and created the auto startup sample. After launched the app for the first time and requested the permission, every time the user logs out and login again, the app will be launched automatically as expected.  I also checked the status in the Task Manager every time, the status of the app won't change once it is enabled.

Comment: I noticed that the sample code only checked the startup status when the app is automatically launched in App.xaml.cs (go through OnActivated). Because you could get the ActivationKind. If you manually launch the app, it won't get startup status information and will just show the default value as Disabled (go through OnLaunched ).

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I see, have you tested it on Surface Hub device with Windows 10 Team OS or just on Windows 10 device? On Windows 10 device it launches when user logs in, however it does not launch on user login on Surface Hub for me.